# Using sed to replace URL

Tags: bash, sed, syntax

I'm having some trouble using sed to replace a string in an sql file.
So far I have:

```
sed -i 's#http://mydomainurl.co.uk#http://pinkiepie#g' /home/user/dbs/my_database.sql
```

Whenever I run this it does remove `http://mydomainurl.co.uk` but replaces it with `http://pinkiepie.co.uk` The local machine at home is called `pinkiepie`, so doesn't need a TLD `.co.uk` suffix, so it should replace it with `http://pinkiepie`

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: works as is here (even if dots should be escaped to be regex-compliant)

Comment: can you clarify what's not working and what are you trying to to achieve

Comment: Yeah. I want to replace http://mydomainurl.co.uk with http://localmachine, but it keeps leaving the .co.uk of the URL, so I get http://localmachine.co.uk

Comment: this works for me... `echo 'replace http://mydomainurl.co.uk' | sed 's#http://mydomainurl.co.uk#http://pinkiepie#g'`

Comment: can you post a sample line of text from your file? also what is your sed version

Comment: the `-i` option may act strangely. Can you try without it?

Comment: check the encoding of your sql file...
`file /home/user/dbs/my_database.sql`

Comment: So it's working now.
`sed -i 's#http://mydomainurl.co.uk#http://pinkiepie#g'`
I have no idea why it didn't work to start with.
Thanks for your help, humans :)

Comment: @toby_lh suggest to close the question

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -i 's,http://localhost:3000/,https://anywebsite.io/,g' ./destination
```

most easy solution

Comment: Best answer! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one to change recursively http to https

```
grep -rl 'href="http://' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/href\=\"http\:\/\//href\=\"https\:\/\//g'
```